# I am continuosly getting error related to GLOG and BOOST anyone have a solution to this?

Tags: linux, cmake, build, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to resolve this error, but couldn't find any solution to this, I tried even installing glog and gflags, still no progress.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package):

```sh
By not providing "Findglog.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"glog", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glog" with
any of the following names:
  glogConfig.cmake
  glog-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "glog" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"glog_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "glog"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at /home/xyz/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
   Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR
   GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   /home/xyz/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
   /home/xyz/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindGTest.cmake:200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
   tests/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

**THIS IS MY RECIPE FILE, any problem here which is causing ERROR???**

```
DESCRIPTION = "First recipe"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/kuscsik/streamfs"
LICENSE = "GPL-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=3db2ce9019f8875eeba1efdc2a5db4c4"
inherit cmake pkgconfig
DEPENDS= "glog"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/kuscsik/streamfs"
SRC_URI += "file://CMake.patch"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to check if yocto provide a recipe (.bb file?) for GLog using a CMake based build and installing the associated config file.

According to this:

1. https://git.congatec.com/yocto/meta-openembedded/-/blob/sumo/meta-oe/recipes-support/glog/glog_0.3.4.bb
   It seems glog use an autotools based build instead of the CMake based build so you can't use it in a dependent CMake project OR you need to provide your own findGlog.cmake module to wrap the autotool install...
2. https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/glog/glog_0.5.0.bb Here glog use a CMake based build -> please verify your glog.bb recipe provided by YOUR setup.

Then in your own recipe you should try to use:

```
DEPENDS = "glog"
```

ref: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-varlocality-recipe-required

Comment: you should publish your recipe in the question instead...

Comment: Done, updated my issues, please help me with it